# ¿ Alguien sabe como conectarse a las tablas de SAP para desarrollar una aplicación web?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php5, sap

que tal??

Mi problema es que estoy desarrollando una aplicación web para una empresa y la misma utiliza el programa 'SAP' para controlar todos sus datos. Este software tiene una base de datos con tablas como si fuera mysql, pero el problema es que no se como conectarme a dicha base de datos para avanzar con el proyecto.

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: y buscate un conector SAP?

Comment: No encontré @gbianchi

Comment: checa esto: http://rdeshapriya.com/connecting-sap-and-php/

Comment: al escribir esto: sap conector php en google salieron un monton de links. Igual sabes que SAP es un tipo de base propietaria, donde no es tan facil sacarle datos asi como asi. Chequeaste con la gente de SAP como hacer esto?

Comment: busca SAP HANA ODBC Drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO sé que versión de SAP utilizas, y si todas las versiones de SAP utilizan la misma Base de Datos, pero en la empresa en que trabajo, utilizamos SAP Businnes One (SAP B1) y la base de datos que utiliza es Microsoft SQL Server (MS SQL).
Entonces, la conexión se hace tan simple como conectarse a este servidor.
Por asuntos de licencia, no pueden hacerse actualizaciones de datos o modificaciones de datos desde fuera deSAP, pero consultas y reportes, no hay problema.

Comment: te saludo y te comento que no se deben responder preguntas tan amplias y basadas en opiniones que por esas dos razones terminarán cerradas, por favor revisa [answer] y de paso haz el [tour]

Comment: Muchas gracias Julio! Voy a preguntar en la empresa a ver cual es la versión de SAP que utilizan y entonces veré si puedo conectarme porque lo que necesito es hacer consultas, no modificaciones y eso entonces creo que con tu sugerencia puedo proceder a seguir con el proyecto